# Issues with a sed command and Enviorment Variables

Tags: linux, terminal

I have a config file called settings.json , an example is below.

```
{
  "token": "inserttokenhere",
  "role": 766507041757069351,
  "channel": 766507042113847383,
}
```

I am trying to use a sed command to replace the value after token (in this example inserttokenhere). The value I will be using to replace it is an enviorment variable. My issue seems to be that the file is full of " already. I have tried a ton of different commands and i can not get any of them to do what i want. The following command is as close as ive gotten (I think). In the below code I am using $LOGHOME as my variable for testing cause its part of the base OS.

```
sed -i "s%"token": "'.*'"%"token": "$LOGHOME""% settings.json
```

What part of this is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you can try something like this, though as mentioned in a comment the right tool would be `jq`:

```
sed '/token/s;[^: ]*$;\"'"$HOME"'\";' settings.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "token": "/home/user"
  "role": 766507041757069351,
  "channel": 766507042113847383,
}
```